# Pila estatica en java

Tags: java, pilas

Tengo un problema con un programa en java ,tengo que hacer una pila estática ya empecé el código pero al correrlo siempre me da e mensaje que la pila esta vacía aunque ya haya insertado elementos ,el código del programa es el siguiente:

```
    public class AppPilaEstatica {
static Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
static final int MAX = 5;
static Object Pila[] = new Object[MAX];
static int tope = -1;


public static void main(String[] args) {
     Object Dato;
     int opc;

    do{
      System.out.println("Menu de pila");
      System.out.println("1. Push");
      System.out.println("2. Pop");
      System.out.println("3. Desplegar Pila");
      System.out.println("4. Salir");
      System.out.println("Teclee la opcion");
      opc = teclado.nextInt();

      switch(opc){
          case 1: 

            System.out.println("Ingrese dato a insertar");
            Dato = teclado.nextInt();

            push(Pila, Dato, tope, MAX);


              break;
          case 2: 

              Dato = pop(Pila, tope);
              if (Dato == null) {
                  System.out.println("El dato que salio es: " + Dato);

              }

              break;
          case 3:

              desplegarPila(Pila, tope);

              break;
          case 4:
              System.out.println("Adios");
          default:
              System.out.println("Error\nOpcion invalida");
      }

    }while(opc!=4);



}

public static boolean pilaVacia(Object Pila[],int tope){
    return tope == -1;

}

public static boolean pilaLlena(Object Pila[], int tope, int MAX){
    return tope == MAX-1;

}
public static void push(Object Pila[],Object Dato,int tope,int MAX){
    if (pilaLlena(Pila, tope, MAX)==true) {
        System.out.println("Overflow");
    } else {
        tope ++;
        Pila[tope] = Dato;
        System.out.println(tope);

    }

}
public static Object pop(Object Pila[],int tope){
    Object Dato = null;
    if (pilaLlena(Pila, tope, MAX) == true) {
        System.out.println("Underflow"); 
    } else {
        Dato = Pila[tope];
        tope --;
    }
    return Dato;
}
public static void desplegarPila(Object Pila[],int tope){

    if (pilaVacia(Pila, tope) == true) {
        System.out.println("-------Pila Vacia--------");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Datos de la pila");
            for (int i = -1; i < tope; i++) {
                System.out.println(Pila[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("---------------------");
    }


}
```

}
Por lo que creo que el problema esta en que en el método pila vacía nunca cambia a false por lo cual no se que podría estar pasando al parecer el valor de tope no cambia pero no logro hacer que el programa funcione 
Por otro lado intente en el método desplegar pila combinar el true por false el la siguiente línea:

```
public static void desplegarPila(Object Pila[],int tope){

if (pilaVacia(Pila, tope) == true)
```

Para que se ejecutara a fuerzas el else pero aun así no me despliega nada 
he buscado mucho y he estado intentando razonar la respuesta pero no se en que me estoy equivocando.

Answer (score 2):

> Tu problema es el siguiente, tenes a tope en los atributos globales, y cuando vas al metodo push le mandas tope por parámetro, en java el pasaje de parametros es por copia. Lo que significa que no trabaja con el tope global sino con el local, cuando agregas un elemento a la pila pones tope++, pero el que estas incrementando es el local, cuando terminas de ejecutar el método las variables locales se eliminan y siempre tenes la pila vacía.
>   push lleva el elemento como parámetro nomas, lo mismo te pasa en pop(), aca te dejo como debería ser tu interface pila (segun los metodos que usas vos).

```
public static boolean pilaVacia();
public static boolean pilaLlena();
public static void push(Object Dato);
public static Object pop();
public static void desplegarPila();
```

> Observa que el único que tiene parámetros es push, los demás datos se sacan de los atributos globales.